# Get maximum weight by unique person with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this data:

```
data = {'name':['dave','bob','barry','bob','dave','barry'],
        'age':[35,30,41,50,44,53],
        'weight':[144,158,150,187,250,197]}
```

I want to grab the heaviest person by weight for each name - so I only want barry to appear once with an of 53 and his weight of 197 as this barry combination is heavier than 41 age barry.

I can get it working but not return back the column of weight - here's the full code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'name':['dave','bob','barry','bob','dave','barry'],
        'age':[35,30,41,50,44,53],
        'weight':[144,158,150,187,250,197]}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df.groupby('name')['age'].max())
```

So, I get back this as my output:

name
barry    53
bob      50
dave     44
Name: age, dtype: int64

I have tried this this:

```
print(df.groupby('name')['age'].max())('weight')
```

but it doesn't work. I need it in the right order, name, age, weight.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('name')['weight'].idxmax()]
```

Output:

```
    name  age  weight
5  barry   53     197
3    bob   50     187
4   dave   44     250
```

---

Alternative:

```
df.sort_values('weight', ascending=False).groupby('name').head(1)
# Or                                                   , as_index=False).first()
```

Output:

```
    name  age  weight
4   dave   44     250
5  barry   53     197
3    bob   50     187
```